# How to handle disconnection / reconnection with windows StreamSocket

Tags: c#, tcp, stream-socket-client, windows-networking

What is the correct way to handle a disconnection and re-connection event with the windows StreamSocket class (TCP)?

I have an issue where calling "Invalid Operation, method was called at an unexpected time" when calling async_connect after a disconnection event

do I need to create a new streamsocket, or wait for some amount of time before attempting to re-connect?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket

Comment: It would be great if you could add a [mcve] to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the following code:

```
// on catching an exception
socket.dispose();
connect();

// connect function
connect():
    socket = new StreamSocket ...
```

It was necessary to 1) call socket.dispose() on the socket which the client disconnected from and 2) create a new socket (socket = new StreamSocket(...)). Reusing the same socket to connect did not work.